# PALANTIR-FOUNDRY: How can I add a description for a dataframe in a transform?

Tags: dataframe, palantir-foundry, field-description

I am producing a dataframe through a transform. In that transform I am able to add Column description the usual way:

```
out_all.write_dataframe(df, column_descriptions=mycols_dictionary)
```

My question is, can I add a dataframe description in a similar way?

Thank u in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way to do it from transforms at the moment. Unlike column descriptions, dataset description is not branchable, meaning the description remains the same across branches (just like dataset name).

Comment: Thank you very much indeed for the answer @proggeo !